# Why is move ctor slower than copy ctor?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, move, copy-constructor

I have the following code to test copy ctor and move ctor of the `std::string` class, and the result surprised me, move ctor is **~1.4** times slower than copy ctor.

To my understanding, move-constructing doesn't need to allocate memory, for the `std::string` case, there may be an internal pointer in the move-constructed object directly set to that of the moved object, it should be faster than allocating memory for the buffer and then copy the content from the object when being copy-constructed.

Here is the code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void CopyContruct(const std::string &s) {
  auto copy = std::string(s);
}

void MoveContruct(std::string &&s) {
  auto copy = std::move(s);
  //auto copy = std::string(std::move(s));
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 50000000; ++i) {
    CopyContruct("hello world");
    //MoveContruct("hello world");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**

From the assembly of the two functions, I can see that for `MoveConstruct` there's an instantiation of the `std::remove_reference` class template, I think this should be the culprit but I am not familiar with assembly, anyone can elaborate on that?

The following code is decompiled on https://godbolt.org/ with x86-64 gcc7.2:

```
CopyContruct(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&):
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  sub rsp, 48
  mov QWORD PTR [rbp-40], rdi
  mov rdx, QWORD PTR [rbp-40]
  lea rax, [rbp-32]
  mov rsi, rdx
  mov rdi, rax
  call std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
  lea rax, [rbp-32]
  mov rdi, rax
  call std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()
  nop
  leave
  ret
MoveContruct(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&):
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  sub rsp, 48
  mov QWORD PTR [rbp-40], rdi
  mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-40]
  mov rdi, rax
  call std::remove_reference<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&>::type&& std::move<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)
  mov rdx, rax
  lea rax, [rbp-32]
  mov rsi, rdx
  mov rdi, rax
  call std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&)
  lea rax, [rbp-32]
  mov rdi, rax
  call std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()
  nop
  leave
  ret
```

**Edit2:**

Things' getting interesting, I changed `std::string` to `std::vector` as @FantasticMrFox mentioned in the comment, the result is the opposite, `MoveConstruct` is `~1.9` times faster than `CopyConstruct`, it seems `std::remove_reference` is not the culprit, but *optimization* of these two classes may be.

**Edit3:**

The following code is compiled on MacOS with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1), with optimization flag -O3.

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .macosx_version_min 10, 11
    .globl  __Z12CopyContructRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE
    .align  4, 0x90
__Z12CopyContructRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE: ## @_Z12CopyContructRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp1:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    pushq   %rbx
    subq    $24, %rsp
Ltmp3:
    .cfi_offset %rbx, -24
    movq    %rdi, %rax
    leaq    -32(%rbp), %rbx
    movq    %rbx, %rdi
    movq    %rax, %rsi
    callq   __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEC1ERKS5_
    movq    %rbx, %rdi
    callq   __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEED1Ev
    addq    $24, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc

    .globl  __Z12MoveContructONSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE
    .align  4, 0x90
__Z12MoveContructONSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE: ## @_Z12MoveContructONSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp4:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp5:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp6:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $32, %rsp
    movq    16(%rdi), %rax
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    movq    (%rdi), %rax
    movq    8(%rdi), %rcx
    movq    %rcx, -16(%rbp)
    movq    %rax, -24(%rbp)
    movq    $0, 16(%rdi)
    movq    $0, 8(%rdi)
    movq    $0, (%rdi)
    leaq    -24(%rbp), %rdi
    callq   __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEED1Ev
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc
```

Comment: If it's the only code in there, it could be that `CopyConstruct` gets optimized more than the other. Your method doesn't have any sideeffect and the parameters are constant. The compiler could optimize and make a function that does nothing. On the other hand the Move one might not get optimized. Thought I'd expect both methods to be optimized as they do nothing and the variable is automatically deleted after it's created in the scope.

Comment: Also string is not a great example anyway, because most implementations use a flyweight model. You may find your copy is not copying at all.

Comment: Hi @LoïcFaure-Lacroix and I have edited the question and attach some assembly, could you take a look at that?

Comment: For what i was talking about: https://ideone.com/2iGnzS  A vector of the same length takes much longer to copy.

Comment: Interesting, but I still  don't know why and what kind of optimization is used in these classes.

Comment: You really need to say what compiler version, library version, and compiler command-line options you are using.  If your library has a small-string optimization, resource stealing may not be possible.

Comment: This is compiled with -O0, Benchmarking unoptimised code is a **waste of time**. Please don't do it.

Comment: @n.m., You are absolutely right, after I add -O3, the two functions are about the same speed, but still not what I expected, I thought move should be a lot faster than copy. I have attached the assembly in the question.

Comment: With -O3 the entire program is a [no-op](https://godbolt.org/g/8KBVfZ). Naturally one no-op is about the same speed as the other no-op.

Comment: @n.m., From the assembly I attached(compiled with `g++ -O3`) I can still see that copy constructor was called for `CopyConstruct` and a lot of move statements for `MoveConstruct`, that is not a no-op.

Comment: Look at the link I provided. `main` is a no-op. That's what you are measuring. Neither of your functions is called. I have marked them static so that the compiler is free to eliminate them entirely, but that's only to unclutter the disassembly. They are not called either way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This kind of microbenchmark is often misleading, because it doesn't test the thing you think it tests.

However, in your case, I can explain the most likely cause of the measurements you're seeing.

`std::string`, in all modern implementations, uses something called the "small buffer optimization", or SBO. (@FantasticMrFox's assertion in the comments about using flyweight is wrong. I don't think any popular implementation ever used flyweight except for the empty string. He means copy-on-write, which was used by GNU's standard library in the past, but GNU switched away because a compliant C++11 string cannot use COW.)

In this optimization, some space is reserved internally in the string object to store short strings and avoid heap allocation for them.

This means the copy and move constructors of string are implemented roughly like this:

```
copy(source) {
  if source length > internal buffer capacity
    allocate space
  copy source buffer to my buffer
}

move(source) {
  if source uses internal buffer {
    copy source buffer to my buffer
    set source length to zero
    set first byte of source buffer to zero
  } else {
    steal source buffer
  }
}
```

As you can see, the move constructor is a bit more complex. It is also a bit more optimized than that in some implementations, but the general logic stays the same.

So for small buffer strings (and I suspect the one you're testing with fits in your particular implementation), there's simply less work to do to copy, because the source string doesn't need to be reset.

But when you turn on full optimizations, the compiler probably recognizes some dead stores and removes them. (Of course, the compiler might just remove your whole benchmark, since it doesn't actually do anything.)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning SBO, I did a another test with a dynamically allocated and big enough `std::string`, the result is more reasonable. move is ~20% faster than copy.

Answer (score 1):

When [I feed your code to clang or gcc with `-O3`](https://godbolt.org/g/sBZKQw) I get from clang:

```
main: # @main
  mov eax, 50000000
.LBB0_1: # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
  add eax, -25
  jne .LBB0_1
  xor eax, eax
  ret
```

and gcc:

```
main:
  xor eax, eax
  ret
```

I did place the functions in an anonymous namespace to get rid of the noise from having to export the functions themselves.  But the main is being completely optimized away.

Microbenchmarks are often misleading.

Comment: You are right, I did another test with the string length printed to stdout and had the output redirected to `/dev/null`, which ensures that the program **does something** meaningful so the compiler doesn't optimize out the code, the result is as what I commented on Sebastian's answer.